# Trying to change Windows 11 registry, update seems to not do much

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, regedit

I am trying to change the key

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e
```

Which is for the 'Specify how long your computer is inactive before your display turns off' (Shown from the value `Description`)

The problem I am experiencing, is when I change this key (The `Attributes` key), it does not adjust the value from the setting menu (Setting > System > Power > Screen and Sleep) even after a restart. The description implies that it is the right key, and I am changing it to `2`. Does it update, but it is not reflected in the settings gui? I'm not sure

Btw the purpose of me doing this is so I can have a script to run some settings for a fresh computer.

Comment: "The description tells me that it is the right key," - Which description?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: Extremely unclear : Which value are you changing to `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of unclear really,...you want to set monitor in script to sleep, but you are trying to do it by showing/hiding a "display" option within advanced "Power Options" menu under "Edit Plan Settings"?

That, ...dword "Attributes"(not key) if set to 1 will hide option in menu, and 2 will show it, has nothign to do with minutes or when,...if that is your aim, i'm sorry,...

where if you wanna use script to set your monitor to XXminutes to do something(0=never), then you want something like;

```
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -monitor-timeout-dc 0
```

To expand on your answer(script wise), if you also want to keep pc more "active" you might also want;

```
Switch hibernation off
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -hibernate-timeout-dc 0

Disable disk power-off
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -disk-timeout-ac 0
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -disk-timeout-dc 0

Set sleep time to zero
%windir%\system32\Powercfg /change -standby-timeout-ac 0
%windir%\system32\powercfg /change -standby-timeout-dc 0
```

Comment: Yup, that works. Question is, where can I find more information about adjusting those settings like that? I see that there is a list of cpl on `https://www.itechtics.com/control-panel-applets-cpl/#What-are-CPL-Files`, but is there any way to inspect them and see what attributes I can change ?

Comment: You mean like;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options